# How to use selected record in a tree view

Tags: odoo

Working on odoo, I would like to select a set of item from a tree view and use a button to call a function to do something with this recordset. But I can't find a way to put a button before the tree...
What is the way to do?
Any idea?
Thanks a lot.
Jeff

Comment: Why a button?, you can easy put an action in the "More" button.

Comment: why has this question gone unanswered for 7 years ?